# How can I list the path of the output of this script?

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, centos

How can I list the path of the output of this script?

This is my command: 
(ls -d */ ); echo -n $i; ls -R $i | grep "wp-config.php" ;

This is my current output: 
/wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want find the path to a file called "wp-config.php".
Does the following help?

```
find $PWD -name 'wp-config.php'
```

Comment: what does your variable `$i` represent? From a fresh terminal point of view, `(ls -d */ ); echo -n $i; ls -R $i` is equivalent to `ls -R`

Answer (score 0):

Your script is kind of confusing: Why does ls -d */ does not show any output? What's the value of $i? Your problem in fact seems to be that `ls -R` lists the contents of all subdirectories but doesn't give you full paths for their contents.

Well, `find` is the best tool for that, but you can simulate it in this case via a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

searchFor=wp-config.php
startDir=${1:-.}

lsSubDir() {
  local actDir="$1"
  for entry in $(ls "$actDir"); do
    if [ -d "$actDir/$entry" ]; then
      lsSubDir "$actDir/$entry"
    else
      [ $entry = $searchFor ] && echo "$actDir/$entry"
    fi
  done
}

lsSubDir $startDir
```

Save it in a file like findSimulator, make it executable and call it with the directory where to start searching as parameter.

Be warned: this script is not very efficient, it may stop on large subdirectory-trees because of recursion. I would strongly recommend the solution using `find`.

Comment: Here is a break down of what the command does: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%28ls+-d+*%2F+%29%3B+echo+-n+%24i%3B+ls+-R+%24i+|+grep+%22wp-config.php%22+%3B

but I am trying to avoid find as much as possible (shared server environment).